# minecraft Launcher problem 20.04

Tags: java, 20.04, minecraft

Ubuntu 20.04
Openjdk 8 and 11
I am trying to run minecraft launcher 1.6.89
and i am getting this problem
I already try to open it on Openjdk 11, then switch to openJdk 8
What next should I try ???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

It is not straight through but it works.
I chose to remove Minecraft launcher downloaded from repository.
I had to install gdebi
Then download official Minecraft Launcher from official website>
Then use gdebi to install Minecraft
sudo gdebi Minecraft.deb
ANd it works